# what version of rxjs does not reference rxjs-compat?

Tags: angular, npm, ng-upgrade

For many days I've been trying to follow and figure out the upgrade process for ng 5.x to 6.x.

I keep getting build issues about not finding rxjs-compat/Observable.

I'm not using nor am I including the rxjs-compat, what version of rxjs should I be using so that it does NOT reference that darn module?

Comment: You want to be using `6.5.x` if you are on Angular `8.x`

Comment: @Reactgular thank you

Comment: @Reactgular what about Angular 6.x?

Comment: Came across same issue, do not know why rxjs-compat is being used in rxjs even though i do not want it to be there.

Comment: @edjm Can you please tell any solution you figured out for this?

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj Honestly, I'm not positive on how I got past the issue. Are you just seeing warnings from npm install process or is the build actually failing? I may have simply added the rjxj to the package.json file to be imported into the project to get past it. Sorry it has been over 2 years since I did that.